# .bootstrapTable execute code after update happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, css-tables

I want to execute code after bootstrap table update.

I have wrote following code:

```
     $selectProductTable.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
        url: REST_PRODUCT_PREFIX + '/list',
        ajaxOptions: {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
            }
        },
        success: function() {
            updateUserInformation($("#userId").val())
        }
    });
```

But succes doesn't invoke.

Can you help to achieve it?

Comment: if you can share some HTML snippet  too with keeping the URL same.

Comment: Excuse me. I didn't catch your comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/develop/dist/bootstrap-table.js#L2014-L2033

Specifically line 2026.  You can see there that on success of the ajax call it triggers an event called: 'load-success.bs.table'.

You can listen to this event doing something like this:

```
  $table.on('load-success.bs.table', function (res) {
    console.log('this is the response from the ajax call: ' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cm44uL3v/2/

The event is called: `onLoadSuccess` and you can find a description of what it does here: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events

Answer (score 1):

```
 $selectProductTable.bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    ...
    onLoadSuccess: function(status, res) {
        // do something
    },
    ...
 });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @cpburnz it just another syntax of m1. answer. Somewhere written that it better, but I am not expert